# How to include OR condition in HTTP request to an API?

Tags: angularjs, api, http, request

I am wondering if it was possible to include a "OR" condition in a URL request.

In my case, I would like to have the list of items which have been created or updated between two dates. (Assuming that items that have been created before these dates but updated during these dates interest me!).

I tired lot of syntax but can't find the right way to do so.. 
I wrote the following code to make my problem more understandable.

```
api/items/search/?query=(created_on_from=2015-05-09&created_on_to=2015-10-
09)OR(updated_on_from=2015-05-09&updated_on_to=2015-10-09)
```

Thanks a lot !

Comment: The way to do both requests depends 100% of the API implementation.
Yo can do that manualy doing 2 request and merging the results on a dictionary.

Comment: Ok, since I do not want to make two different requests I will work on API implementation. Thanks!